# When do I need the cassette low spacer

Tags: shimano, cassette

I want to install a CS-HG800-11 cassette on my Zipp 303s wheelset. The cassette comes with a low spacer (Y4T724000) and I am not sure whether I need it and if so which way should I put it on the freehub body? On side of the spacer is flat the other one is not.
Help would be nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t say what size the cassette is but presumably it is a wide range model.

11 speed compatible freehub bodies are 1.8mm longer than 8-10 speed ones. Some wide range 11 speed cassettes can fit on a 10 speed freehub because the the large diameter inner sprockets can overhang the inner end of the freehub body a little and clear the drive side flange and spokes. Such cassettes come with a 1.8mm spacer for installation on a 11 speed freehub.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry. it is a 11-34 cassette.

Comment: Yep, 11-34 will need the spacer.

Comment: ...unless it's a pre-11-speed 303..